# How to compute stack size in Java?

Tags: java, stack

How to use java code to compute the stack size?
Is there any way to use code to compute the stack size?

Comment: Calculate *what* stack size? The amount you are currently using? The amount that was allocated? The amount you think you will need for some unstated computation?

Comment: I'm thinking of calculating the stack size limit.

Comment: @ZhaoyangShao, why do you need it? What's your initial problem?

Comment: @TagirValeev it's an interview question. They asked whats the common stack size for computer and how can we compute the stack size

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard or the way to calculate the Stack size. You can't do that without some complex JVM-specific API. So, I think you should not do that.

However there is a way you can adjust maximum stack size in VM via `ss` option. Please refer:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp1024112
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using say linked list to make a stack then by the following code you can get the number of elements currently in the stack:

```
public int getSize() {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int size = 0;
    Node tmpNode = head;
    while (tmpNode.next != null) {
        size++;
        tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Now you can get the size stack is occupying by multiplying the size returned by above function with the required factor.
**Say for example the Stack only has integer values then the memory occupied by the stack = 4*size;**

Comment: So how do you get the linked list?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62710/stack-implementation-using-a-linked-list

Comment: It is the code implementing stacks using linked list.